# Determine address of global variable

Tags: llvm

What is the easiest way to determine the address of a global variable during the LLVM compilation process?

I want to determine the address of a global variable as well as modifying its content.

Comment: if you are talking about in it, then when you are using globals, you are dealing with global variable pointer and when you create CreateLoad(global_ptr) you are using the value. global ptr is also a value and it self contains the address.

Comment: But in such a way you are determining the address at runtime. I want to determine this address statically during compilation/linking in way that I get the information saying gobal variable x is located at memory location 0x20000200 for example.